# relationship of 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 tables: animalstudies, especies and procedences, where

```
animalstudy belongs_to especie
animalstudy has_many_procedences
especie has_many animalstudies
procedence belongs_to animalstudy
```

When I create a procedence, I can associate it to an especie pulled from a select this way:

```
f.select :animalstudy_id, Animalstudy.all.collect(|as| [as.especie.name, as.id]}
```

I want to show the name from the especie choosed instead of id in the procedences views (index and show). At console, I’m trying to do this way:

```
p=Procedence.first
name = p.animalstudy.especie.name
```

and it give me this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `especie' for nil:NilClass.
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Remember it's relationship many to many, don't forget the has_many through.

I think that do it:

```
animalstudy
has_many :procedences
has_many :especies, through: procedences

especies
has_many :procedences
has_many :animalstudies, through: procedences

procedence
belongs_to :animalstudy
belongs_to :especie
```

Maybe this was relationship more correct. See ya, and rate me please.

Comment: This is not a many-to-many relationship because animalstudy is not related only especies, but in other objects too (captures,cirurgies, etc). In each object has a animalstudy_id field whence I want to show the especie value from especies table  (not the especie_id field, but the name field from especie table associated).

Comment: class AnimalStudy < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :form
    belongs_to :especie
    has_many :procedences
    has_many :bioterioexperiments
    has_many :alimentarregime
    has_many :alimentarconditions
    has_many :cirurgies
    has_many :anoespecies, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :anoespecies, reject_if: proc { |atr| atr['ano'].blank? and atr['valor'.blank?] }, allow_destroy: true

Comment: It’s Ok. What was wrong was field name animalstudy_id in plural in some tables.